# Faces don't look the same after deleted and filled with F.How to fix deleted faces issue?

Tags: modeling, faces, topology

I have made this model without deleting a lot of faces. But at the beginning I deleted all faces from this line and restored them using "F"(fill) shortcut. Now it's looking weird, I cant select all the lines from it too. I already tried to Recalculate normals outside and inside but no luck. How to fix this? I'm trying to make all faces look the same
[image: Problem image]

[image: Cant select whole line with double click]

[image: The line stops then I double click]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

probably there are multiple stray vertices there?

Comment: I used wireframe and saw a edge cutting everything in the middle. Deleted them and problem is gone, thank you a lot